# attr con jquery me regresa undefined

Tags: jquery, atributos

Tengo un `select` que lleno de manera dinámica al consultar mi base de datos. Usando `$("#mi_id").val()` obtengo el valor correctamente, pero lo que necesito es obtener la etiqueta que se ha seleccionado, pero `$("#mi_id").attr("nombre_atributo");` me regresa `undefined`.

Esta es la forma en que lleno las opciones del `select` y con lo cual no tengo problemas:

archivo r_egresos.php

```
<select id="proveedor" name="proveedor" class="form-control" autofocus required></select>

function b_proveedor() {
    var proveedores = "";
    $.ajax({
        url:"egresos_controller.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data: { axn: "b_proveedor" },
        type:"POST",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != null || data != "") {
                proveedores += '<option value="0">---</option>' 
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    proveedores += '<option data-nproveedor="'+value["nombre"]+'" value="'+value["id_proveedor"]+'">'+value["nombre"]+'</option>'
                });
            } else {
                proveedores += '<option value="0">No hay registros</option>'
                proveedores += '<option value="0">---</option>' 
            };
            $("#proveedor").empty().append(proveedores);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    })
}
```

Y de esta forma es como estoy tratando de obtener la etiqueta:

archivo Funciones.js

```
$("#proveedor").on("change", function() {
    var data1 = $('#proveedor').data("nproveedor");
    var data2 = $('#proveedor').val();
    var data3 = $('#proveedor').attr("nproveedor");
    var data4 = $('#proveedor').attr("data-nproveedor");
});
```

Pero me regresa `undefined`.

Ya pobre con `data-nproveedor="'+value["nombre"]+'"` pero al tratar de leerlo me regresa también `undefined`.

Comment: ¿Por alguna razón usas `nproveedor`? Porque si lo que buscas es el obtener el texto de la opción seleccionada puedes obtenerlo sin tener que crear un `attr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los elementos que tienen asignada la propiedad `data-nproveedor` son los elementos `options` dentro del `select`. Sin embargo estás intentando acceder a la propiedad `data` del `select` en sí mismo. Observa el siguiente snippet, creo que te dará una idea de dónde está tu error:

```js
var $select = $('select');

$select.on('change', function () {
  $option = $select.find('option:selected');
  console.log( $option.data('atributo') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option data-atributo="valor 1" value="1">número 1</option>
  <option data-atributo="valor 2" value="2">número 2</option>
  <option data-atributo="valor 3" value="3">número 3</option>
  <option data-atributo="valor 4" value="4">número 4</option>
  <option data-atributo="valor 5" value="5">número 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias..... Tienes toda la razón, tenía que obtener la opción seleccionada. Es la solución perfecta

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas resuelto, @JavierMMM

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
 proveedores += '<option nproveedor="'+value["nombre"]+'"value="'+value["id_proveedor"]+'">'+value["nombre"]+'</option>'});
```

Reemplaza por:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
 proveedores += '<option data-nproveedor="'+value["nombre"]+'"value="'+value["id_proveedor"]+'">'+value["nombre"]+'</option>'});
```

Comment: No me funciona, he usado de la siguiente manera y nada:

      <option data-nproveedor="'+value["nombre"]+'" value="'+value["id_proveedor"]+'">'+value["nombre"]+'</option>

y trato de leerlo de las siguiente formas y nada:
   var data1 = $('#proveedor').data("nproveedor");
   var data4 = $('#proveedor').attr("data-nproveedor");
el resultado es el mismo, undefined

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega todos el código que crees que hace falta para que podamos reproducir tu escenario :)

Comment: Ese es el código completo